# How to rename folder in network shared folder?

Tags: c#

I need to rename folder on network (I am using VPN).
Since this is on network I have to connect using credentials. I have all permissions to read and write in shared folder.
Same logic with connection to network is working when I want to delete, edit or save in same folder.

Same function is working for rename files.

Problem is just when I want to rename Folder !

This is function:

```
   public async Task<bool> Rename(string oldPath, string newPath )
    {
        using (var network = new NetworkConnection(configuration.Value.Host, networkCredential))
        {
            network.Connect();
            File.Move(oldPath, newPath);
            return await Task.FromResult(true);
        }
    }
```

For example this are function parameters:

> oldPath =>   \\10.174.133.199\SharedFolder\MyFolder
>
> newPath => \\10.174.133.199\SharedFolder\RenamedFolder

Comment: Looks like the issue is you using `File.Move` - a folder is ***not*** a file, as such you should use `Directory.Move` instead

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre make that comment an answer please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are facing is that you are using `File.Move` - a folder is not a `File`, but instead a `Directory`, as such you should use `Directory.Move` instead

```
Directory.Move(oldPath, newPath);
```